# dateoffset on dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeoffset

I got a Pandas dataframe and a column that 
is called expiration  that has  `datetime64[ns]` datatype.
`df.['expiration'][0]` gives `Timestamp('2010-12-31 00:00:00')`.

I want to substract a calendar day from this column but can't figure out how.
I tried `pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(days=1)` but this gives the error
cannot use a non-absolute DateOffset in datetime/timedelta operations `[<DateOffset: kwds={'days': 1}>]`

THis is obviously because it only works on timeindex.
So I tried

```
import pandas
df['expiration']=df['expiration']-pandas.datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

but this results in another error:

> type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'

How to do it in a way tht works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 problems.  firstly pandas.datetime is the datetime.datetime class not the module, so you need to reference the datetime.timedelta class directly.  Secondly you need to take 1 day away from every value in the column.  I would do:

```
import datetime as dt
df['expiration'] = df['expiration'].apply(lambda x: x - dt.timedelta(days=1))
```

To vectorise this you need to convert the timedelta into a numpy.timedelta64:

```
df['expiration'] = df['expiration'] - pt.timedeltas.to_timedelta(dt.timedelta(days=1))
```

or create the numpy.timedelta64 directly:

```
df['expiration'] = df['expiration'] - numpy.timedelta64(1, 'D')
```

Comment: That's not vectorized, though.

Comment: Added vectorised solution

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, why does dt.timedelta work in the iterative fashion and not in the vectorized code line? Things like df['mycolumn']=df['mycolumn']+2 are working, though.

Comment: My guess is that there is simply no typecasting in place between datetime.timedelta and numpy.timedelta64, whereas there is typecasting for int -> numpy.timedelta64.  Or maybe timedelta64 is an integer type underneath and therefore numpy casts automatically.  It looks like a feature that could be added.